# Нахождение пяти нечётных делителей в промежутке чисел

Tags: python, алгоритм

**Задача:**
Найдите все натуральные числа, принадлежащие отрезку [35 000 000; 40 000 000], у которых ровно пять различных нечётных делителей (количество чётных делителей может быть любым). В ответе перечислите найденные числа в порядке возрастания.

**Моё решение:**

```py
for number in range(35000000, 40000000+1):
    divs = []
    for div in range(1, round(number**0.5)+1, 2):
        if number%div == 0:
            divs.append(div)
            if number**0.5 != int(number**0.5):
                s = number // div
                if s%2 ! =0:
                    divs.append(s)
    if len(divs) == 5:
        print(number)
```

**Ответ к задаче должен быть таким:**
35819648
38950081
39037448
39337984

*Хотелось бы узнать почему мой код является не рабочим, ибо вместо этих четырёх чисел я получаю множество чисел, которые даже не доходят до первого числа из корректного ответа?*

Comment: похоже, что 35819648 делится только на 23 и 529. там все хорошо с условиями ?

Comment: @splash58 23, 23*23, 23*23*23, 23*23*23*23 - Может, они единицу тоже считают.

Comment: @Igor, впрочем, не поспоришь :)

Comment: Судя по всему считают и единицу и само число

Comment: Кстати, у вас неправильно устроен цикл. пусть число равно 48, round(number**.5)  даст 8 . вы не найдете пару 4*12 потому что 4  - чётное, а 12 больше корня

Comment: @splash58 Так это чётные делители, тут как-раз всё нормально. Я же написал в ответе в чём там прикол )

Comment: да я четные привел, потому что вариант с нечетными не придумал, а суть та же

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Это не ответ на ваш вопрос, а другой подход к решению задачи. Можно проверять числа, разлагая их на делители, а можно конструировать подходящие числа из делителей.

Разложим искомое число на простые. Так как в дальнейшем нас будут интересовать нечётные делители, степень двойки выписана отдельно:

*n = 2<sup>k<sub>0</sub></sup> p<sub>1</sub><sup>k<sub>1</sub></sup> p<sub>2</sub><sup>k<sub>2</sub></sup> ... p<sub>i</sub><sup>k<sub>i</sub></sup>*,

где *k<sub>0</sub>* - целое неотрицательное, *k<sub>1</sub>, k<sub>2</sub>, ..., k<sub>i</sub>* - натуральные, *p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, ..., p<sub>i</sub>* - различные нечётные простые.

Любой делитель *n* конструируется как произведение простых из разложения выше. Сколько нечётных делителей мы можем сконструировать? *(k<sub>1</sub> + 1)(k<sub>2</sub> + 1) ... (k<sub>i</sub> + 1)*. Это произведение может быть равно пяти только если у числа ровно один нечётный простой делитель, который возводится в четвёртую степень.

Подробности можно посмотреть тут: [функция делителей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9).

Искомое число должно иметь вид *2<sup>k</sup> p<sup>4</sup>*, где *k* - целое неотрицательное, *p* - нечётное простое. Сами нечётные делители тогда имеют вид *1, p, p<sup>2</sup>, p<sup>3</sup>, p<sup>4</sup>*.

Будем искать такие числа в нужном диапазоне. Функция `is_prime` написана как можно проще, оценка показывает, что проверять числа больше 80 не нужно:

```
def is_prime(n):
    return all(n % i != 0 for i in range(2, n))


def numbers(m, n):
    i = 3
    while True:
        if is_prime(i):
            j = i ** 4
            if n < j:
                break
            while j <= n:
                if m <= j:
                    yield j
                j *= 2
        i += 2


print(*sorted(numbers(35_000_000, 40_000_000)), sep='\n')
```

> ```
> $ time python five_odd_divisors.py 
> 35819648
> 38950081
> 39037448
> 39337984
>
> real  0m0.021s
> user  0m0.020s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Comment: Опередили! Готовил такой же ответ, позвонили, надо было помочь - отвлекся минут на 30, и все - кто не успел, тот опоздал... :) Забавно, но даже код начинался одинаково - с определения `is_prime`...

Comment: @Harry, обогнать вас - это честь.

Comment: А чего is_prime такая неоптимальная?

Comment: `is_prime` неоптимальная, так как проверять числа больше 80 в данном примере не нужно. `80^4 > 40000000`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а, я этот момент не увидел. Думал, там сами числа проверяются.

Comment: До 80 можно вообще просто в список или сет положить и проверять там или нет.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала приведу код, с которым мне удалось получить правильные ответы. Мне пришлось использовать `numba.njit`, потому что подсчёт идёт долго не смотря на некоторые оптимизации, которые я применил. Код выполняется порядка 2 минуты в `Google Colab`, а если не использовать `numba`, то обещает считать 50 минут, я не стал ждать проверять точное время.

```
from numba import njit

@njit()
def func():
    for number in range(35000000, 40000000+1):
        divs = []
        for div in range(1, int(number**0.5)+1):
            if div%2 and not number%div:
                divs.append(div)
                if len(divs) > 5:
                    break
            nd = number//div
            if nd%2 and nd == number/div and nd!=div:
                divs.append(nd)
                if len(divs) > 5:
                    break
        if len(divs) == 5:
            print(number, divs)

func()
```

Вывод:

```
35819648 [1, 23, 279841, 529, 12167]
38950081 [1, 38950081, 79, 493039, 6241]
39037448 [1, 4879681, 47, 103823, 2209]
39337984 [1, 7, 49, 343, 2401]
```

Теперь к сути. На самом деле вы не можете рассматривать только нечётные делители до корня из числа. Эта оптимизация хорошо работала для других подобных задач, но тут она не корректна. Ведь может получиться так, что у числа есть **нечётный делитель больше корня из числа**, которому соответствует **чётный делитель меньший корня**. А вы эти **чётные делители не перебираете** (шаг 2 у `range`) и поэтому вообще не увидите тот большой нечётный делитель!

Comment: спасибо, но мне бы решение в рамках реализации на ЕГЭ:D

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин Ну тут надо как-то ещё думать. Без `numba.jit` обещает 50 минут считать :D

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин В принципе, если рассматривать не только нечётные это только в 2 раза замедляет перебор, так что получается почти ваш код по сути. Но если надо ещё как-то ускорять - надо что-то придумывать. Пока не знаю что.

Comment: понял. просто ответ к этой задаче приводится на паскале и даже если его перевести на питон, код также не справляется с промежутком:/

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин Мой код работает, просто долго. Ваш код думаю тоже работает не быстро. Есть вообще ограничение на время там или на что вообще ограничения?

Comment: егэ пишется 3 часа 55 минут. это задание является 25-ым из 27 заданий. вообще это СтатГрадовский вариант 25-го задания(они делают всегда усложнёенные) и не факт что такое задание вообще будет. обычно в этом задании надо найти просто числа с 6 делителями или же числа с 3 делителями  кроме единицы и самого числа. всё это легко делается, но просто хочется подготовиться к сложным типам заданий на всякий случай. мой код работает, вроде как, но выдаёт абсолютно не то что нужно. даже близко.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин Ну вот прочитайте моё объяснение внизу моего ответа, почему ваш код не находит некоторые делители и поэтому выдаёт как правильные неверные ответы

Comment: просто всё сделано так, что правильно написанный код выдаёт решение к заданию за секунду-две. это всё учитывается составителями заданий.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин Ну, тогда надо придумывать ещё какие-то оптимизации. Я объяснил, почему ваш код неправильно работает и как сделать, чтобы работал. Как его так сильно ускорить я пока не придумал.

Answer (score 0):

Использован только базовый синтаксис:

```
def is_primenumber(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

x = 35000000
y = 40000000
counter = 0
for j in range(3, int(y ** (1 / 4)) + 1):
    if is_primenumber(j):
        l = j ** 4
        while l <= y:
            if l >= x and l <= y:
                print(l)
            l *= 2
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Привидите, пожалуйста, код в текстовом виде.

Answer (score 0):

```
simple_numbers = []
for i in range(1,round(40000000**0.25)):
    count = 0
    for j in range(1,i):
        if i%j == 0:
            count+=1
    if count == 1:
        simple_numbers.append(i**4)

for i in range(35000000,40000001):
    sm_nmbr = i
    while sm_nmbr % 2 == 0:
        sm_nmbr /= 2
    if sm_nmbr in simple_numbers:
        print(i)
```

Сначала находим все простые числа до корня 4 степени максимального числа для оптимизации счета (они в свою очередь нечетные) и все полученные числа возводим обратно в 4 степень и сохраняем в массив.  Далее от каждого числа отсеиваем степени двойки, т.к это четные числа. И если получившееся число лежит в массиве, то оно подходит по условию.
А условие таково, что n=(a1+1)(a2+1)(a3+1), где n кол-во делителей, a1 - степень числа 1,а так как любое число в 0 степени равно 1, подставляем 0, a2 - степень числа 2 и далее по порядку простых чисел. Т.к мы не учитываем двойки (a2+1) исключаем, a1 всегда будет равна 1, а вот a3 - это степень какого-то простого числа. То есть a3 будет равна 4 для выполнения условия (5 нечетных делителей). n = 1*(1+4) = 5 И методом подбора через цикл for выявляем подходящие числа.

Вывод

```
35819648
38950081
39037448
39337984
```