# Сравнение скорости языков. Неужели Pascal самый быстрый?

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация, производительность, скорость

Всем привет!
Решая очередную задачу из ЕГЭ наткнулся на задание:

> Найдите все натуральные числа, принадлежащие отрезку [106 000 000; 107 000 000], у которых ровно три различных чётных делителя. В ответе перечислите найденные числа в порядке возрастания.

Написал решение на Python:

```
for number in range(106000000 ,107000000 + 1):
    countDel = 0
    if number % 2 == 1:
        continue
    for j in range(1, round(number ** 0.5) + 1):
        if number % j == 0:
            if j % 2 == 0:
                countDel += 1
            if number // j % 2 == 0:
                countDel += 1
            if number == j * j:
                countDel -= 1
        if countDel > 3:
            break
    if countDel == 3:
        print(number)
```

Работает достаточно медленно, как и ожидалось, и у меня возникла замечательная идея написать на более быстром языке и выбрал С++ (Visual Studio)
Написал код:

```
#include <cmath>
int main()
{   
    for (int number = 106000000; number < 107000001; number++) {
        int countDel = 0;
        if (number % 2 == 1) continue;
        for (int j = 1; j <= round(sqrt(number)); j++)
        {
            if (number % j == 0) {
                if (j % 2 == 0) countDel ++;
                if (number / j % 2 == 0) countDel ++;
                if (number == j * j) countDel--;
            }
            if (countDel > 3) break;
        }
        if (countDel == 3) { 
            std::cout << number << std::endl;
        }
   }
}
```

Отлично, работает быстрее, однако решил проверить задание из примера и удивился, что код на Pascal`е, по сути идентичный, работает в 2 раза быстрее:

```
var 
    count, i, j: longint;
    sqrtI: real;
begin
    for i := 106000000 to 107000000 do begin
        count := 1;
        if i mod 2 = 0 then begin
            for j := 2 to round(sqrt(i)) do begin
                if i mod j = 0 then
                    if j mod 2 = 0 then count := count + 1;
                if i mod j = 0 then
                    if (i div j) mod 2 = 0 then count := count + 1;
                if (j * j = i) and (j mod 2 = 0) then count := count - 1;
                if count > 3 then break;
            end;
        end;
        if count = 3 then writeln(i);
        count := 1;
    end;
end.
```

Получается, что Pascal самый быстрый язык программирования и всё это время нам врали?

Comment: Release / Debug

Comment: `Сравнение скорости языков.` языки - это набор синтаксических правил по сути, они не быстрые и не меддленные, у них нет вообще никакой скорости. Одна и так же программа может быть собрана с разными ключами, заточена под разные платформы, у каждого фреймворка также есть свои фишки. Потому факт того, что какая то программа работает медлненнее/быстрее другой не означает для языка программирования ничего.

Comment: Покажите точные параметры запуска/компиляции для каждого из языков, иначе говорить здесь не о чем

Comment: Эту задачу можно решать не "в лоб", а хитрее... Посмотрите сюда - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1276027/195342 - и подумайте немного. У вас подход будет иной, но в чем-то похожий :)

Comment: [Это вряд ли...](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/fpascal-gpp.html)  (все сравнения начинаются [тут](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/index.html))

Answer (score 6):

Мне стало любопытно сравнить С++ и Pascal.

Платформа Linux Ubuntu, 64-bit. Компиляторы:

```
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.0+dfsg-2 [2016/01/28] for x86_64
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-23ubuntu1~16.04)
```

Командные строки:

```
fpc -O4 pascal.pas
g++ -O3 -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror cpp.cpp
```

Результаты прогона:

```
$ time ./pascal
106084178
106492418
106784498
106842962

real    0m7.114s
user    0m7.112s
sys 0m0.004s

$ time ./a.out
106084178
106492418
106784498
106842962

real    0m1.179s
user    0m1.176s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Чуда не произошло: С++ компилятор в данном конкретном случае выдает в шесть раз более быстрый код.

**P.S.** Разница велика. Я проверил различные оптимизации доступные на платформах. GCC без оптимизаций замедляется в четыре раза, FPC во всех вариантах `-Cf??? -Op???` показывает одно время - разница не более десяти процентов.

**P.P.S.** Я буду благодарен если вы укажите мне мои промахи. Возможно, я не умею использовать FPC.

Comment: Это особо одарённый компилятор попался ;) (release был включён?) Тест на Delphi и VS добавил в свой ответ. Впрочем, автор, как провокатор - закинул удочку и пропал ;)

Comment: Я и сам озадачен. Кто-нибудь умеет правильно выбирать и использовать компиляторы Паскаля?

Comment: Да нечего особо выбирать. Живые - Delphi и Free Pascal (FPC), на GNU Pascal, похоже, давно забили, есть ещё дотнетовские Oxygene и учебный PascalABC.net. Про тонкости использования FPC я ничего не могу сказать, только знаю, что у него бывают такие странности в кодогенерации.

Answer (score 5):

```
for j := 2 to round(sqrt(i)) do begin
```

Паскаль оценивает предел цикла внутреннего цикла `for` (где используется медленная вещественная операция `sqrt`) только один раз перед каждым запуском этого цикла.

Как дело обстоит с С++ - вероятно, зависит от оптимизатора.

В целом же обычно компиляторы C++ выдают код лучшего качества.

Есть ещё важный вопрос - как Вы измеряли? Какова точность?

---

Сделал тест. На 3.1 ГГц процессоре поколения Haswell (Xeon 1220v3, примерно как i5 4440) Delphi выдаёт 1.4 с.

C++ VS 2017 (стоит максимальная оптимизация -O2, как -O3 включить в среде - я не знаю) тратит 5.7 с. Если заменить предполагаемую зловредную строку на одноразовое вычисление

```
    int s = round(sqrt(number));
    for (int j = 1; j <= s; j++)
```

то время становится 1.2 с, что вполне согласуется с обычным соотношением скорости генерируемого кода на простых примерах (при возможности векторизации и т.п. компиляторы C++ дадут жару).

Судя по тесту Stanislav Volodarskiy, gcc c -O3 догадывается, как лучше оптимизировать.

Comment: Можете по-подробней рассказать про «Паскаль оценивает предел цикла `for` <…> только один раз». У нас же значение `round(sqrt(i))` будет меняться каждый раз, когда меняется `i`, как он может оценить его лишь единожды?

Comment: Один раз перед каждым запуском внутреннего цикла, конечно. Внесу уточнение, чтобы не было двусмысленно

Comment: Ну тогда тут разницы между Pascal и C++ нет: не вижу причин для компилятора C++ считать это выражение дважды.

Comment: @eanmos Для этого компилятор C должен быть точно уверен, что функции round и sqrt детерминированны и не имеют побочных эффектов, а вот располагает ли он такой информацией, это большой вопрос. В общем случае синтаксис оператора for подразумевает полное выполнение выражения сравнения на каждой итерации.

Comment: @eanmos В Паскале Вирт завещал, что в настоящем for пределы непременно оцениваются один раз. Компилятору С++ разрешено оценивать единожды (формального описания разрешения не нашёл), но он не обязан это делать Executes init-statement once, then executes statement and iteration_expression repeatedly, until the value of condition becomes false. **The test takes place before each iteration.** [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)

Comment: @Mike, MBo, ну это понятно, но компилятор может менять программу как угодно, пока это не меняет observable behavior (as if rule). И очевидно, что он в общем случае не может понять, есть ли у сторонних функций побочные эффекты или нет, но ведь `round` и `sqrt` — это библиотечные функции и у них нет побочных эффектов. Какие могут быть побочные эффекты у `round` и `sqrt`?

Comment: @eanmos Это мы с вами знаем, что они без побочек. Но откуда об этом должен знать компилятор ? И даже если вдруг знает, при каких уровнях оптимизации он может идти на риск, менять строго описанное в документации поведение for. И какой уровень оптимизации был применен ТС

Comment: @Mike, ну кстати, я тут открыл стандарт и как оказалось, `sqrt` имеет побочный эффект: при domain error она может изменить `errno`. Так что да, вы с MBo были правы.

Answer (score 3):

Если правильно написать - быстрее С++ не получится :)

Если подумать - то это числа вида 2*p*p, где p - простое число. Так что...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

bool is_prime(unsigned long x)
{
    unsigned long n = sqrt(x);
    if (x%2 == 0) return false;
    for(unsigned long  i = 3; i <= n; i+=2)
    {
        if (x%i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    for(int n = sqrt(106000000/2)-1; n < sqrt(107000001/2)+1; n++)
    {
        if (is_prime(n))
        {
            int m = n*n*2;
            if (m <= 107000001 && m >= 106000000) std::cout << m << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Время просто не фиксируется :) - https://ideone.com/FBKkw8

Ну, а по вашему вопросу Pascal vs С++ - надо сравнивать не абстрактные шарообразные компиляторы в вакууме, а конкретные компиляторы, с указанием настроек оптимизации и многого другого. Думаю, что по скорости они как минимум сравнимы, и различие в 2 раза - не внутренне присущее Pascal, а конкретные настройки конкретного компилятора...

Увы, Pascal на машине не держу, так что поработать с вашими кодами не могу, это так, просто теоретические рассуждения.

Comment: Мне кажется у вас опечатка :) в слове "c++" вы допустили сразу 3 неверных символа :) замените "c++" на "asm" смысл не поменяется :) Ну а по сути - самым быстрым будет "правильный" алгоритм а не язык программирования или компилятор :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Интересно, какое количество смайликов надо поставить, чтоб самые серьезные люди поняли, что написана шутка?...

Comment: не ожидал видеть на данном сайте шуток :) буду внимательней :) на смайлики редко реагирую как на указатель шутки ;)