# Объясните как работает программа, пожалуйста

Tags: python, алгоритм, циклы, if, for

Дана задача:
Найдите все натуральные числа, принадлежащие отрезку [101 000 000; 102 000 000], у которых ровно три различных чётных делителя (при этом количество нечётных делителей может быть любым). В ответе перечислите найденные числа в порядке возрастания
Есть решение:

```
for N in range (101000000,102000000+1):
p= (N/2)**0.5
if p==int(p):
    k=0
    for i in range (2,int(p//2)+1):
        if p%i==0:
         k+=1
         break

    if k==0: print(N)
```

нужно объяснить как работает данный код. Прям по каждой строчке.

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1276104/195342 — а главное, ответы к нему, и вы поймете, как работает правильная программа. Кстати, она достаточно неэффективна — в смысле проверки числа на простоту...

Answer (score 0):

Код неверно форматирован, правильно так:

```
for N in range (101000000,102000000+1): # Цикл по всем числам
    p = (N/2)**0.5  # Проверка, что число имеет вид 2*p*p, где p - простое
    if p==int(p):   # См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1276104/195342
        k=0         # Проверка числа p на простоту
        for i in range (2,int(p//2)+1): # В цикле перебираются все возможные делители
            if p%i==0:
                k+=1
                break

        if k==0: print(N)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Но можно поподробнее на счет 2 строчки и 4 ( int(p//2) ) строчки

Comment: Вторая и третья строчки означают -  "если половина числа является полным квадратом", т.е его можно представить так, как написано в комментарии в ответе `2*p^2`. Например, `98 = 2*49`.  А что с делителями непонятно?

Comment: почему int(p//2)

Comment: Потому что наибольший делитель числа, кроме него самого, не может быть более половины числа. Для проверки простоты это даже слишком высокий предел, достаточно проверять числа до sqrt(p)

Comment: Да потому что единственный вариант, когда их именно три штуки - такой.