# Подсчёт чисел с 5 нечётными делителями

Tags: python, алгоритм

Найдите все натуральные числа, принадлежащие отрезку [45 000 000; 50 000 000], у которых ровно пять различных нечётных делителей (количество чётных делителей может быть любым). В ответе перечислите найденные числа в порядке возрастания.

```
a = 4500000
b = 5000000
count = 0
for i in range(a,b+1):
    print(i)
    ds = []
    for d in range(1,i+1,2):
        if i%d == 0:
            ds.append(d)
            if len(ds) >5:
                break
if len(ds) == 5:
    print(i)
```

Надо оптимизировать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нахождение пяти нечётных делителей в промежутке чисел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1276027/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ну вот, а я уже решил... Впрочем, у нас решения немного разные.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я ещё интересный способ прикрутил.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Число можно делить на 2 пока оно не станет нечётным - ответ от этого не поменяется.

В каком случае нечётных делителей 5? Посмотрим на число простых множителей.

1. x = a => 1, a - очевидно не подходит.
2. x = a*b => 1, a, b, a*b - мало.
3. x = a*b*c => 1, a, b, c, a*b, a*c, b*c - много, но может быть что-то совпадает?

   - x = a*a*c => 1, a, a<sup>2</sup>, c, a*c, a<sup>2</sup>*c - много
   - x = a*a*a => 1, a, a<sup>2</sup>, a<sup>3</sup> - мало
4. x = a*b*c*d => много, частные случаи:

   - x = a*a*b*b => 1, a, a<sup>2</sup>, a*b, b, b<sup>2</sup>, a<sup>2</sup>*b<sup>2</sup> - много
   - x = a<sup>4</sup> => 1, a, a<sup>2</sup>, a<sup>3</sup>, a<sup>4</sup> - ровно 5
   - остальное не подойдёт
5. 5 и больше тоже не подойдёт

Итак, надо найти числа вида: **2<sup>k</sup> * p<sup>4</sup>**, где p - простое, k - целое неотрицательное.

---

https://ideone.com/DaDKUN

```
def isOddNumberPrime(n):
  for x in range(3, n, 2):
    if x*x > n:
      return True
    if n % x == 0:
      return False

p = [x for x in range(3, 100, 2) if isOddNumberPrime(x)]
p4s = { x**4 for x in p }

l = 45000000
r = 50000000
res = []

for n in range(l, r+1):
  x = n
  while (x & 1) == 0:
    x >>= 1
  if x in p4s:
    res.append(n)

print(res)
```

В заданном диапазоне [45 000 000; 50 000 000] таких чисел 4: 45212176, 45265984, 47458321, 48469444.

---

А можно сделать ещё оптимальнее: найти все подходящие числа, а потом из них выбрать те, что попадают в заданный диапазон.

https://ideone.com/qWNVTr

```
def isOddNumberPrime(n):
  for x in range(3, n, 2):
    if x * x > n: return True
    if n % x == 0: return False

p4m = [x**4 for x in range(3, 100, 2) if isOddNumberPrime(x)]
ok = []
LIM = 50000000

while True:
  i,x = min(enumerate(p4m), key = lambda x: x[1])
  if x > LIM: break
  ok.append(x)
  p4m[i] *= 2

l = 45000000
r = 50000000
print(sum(1 for x in ok if l <= x <= r))
```

Или даже так пооптимальнее, если отказаться от получения отсортированного списка (впрочем, он довольно мелкий и выгоднее отсортировать его позднее): https://ideone.com/V9cfGr

```
def isOddNumberPrime(n):
  for x in range(3, n, 2):
    if x * x > n: return True
    if n % x == 0: return False

ok = []
LIM = 50000000

for x in range(3, 100, 2):
  if isOddNumberPrime(x):
    x = x**4
    while x <= LIM:
      ok.append(x)
      x *= 2

l = 45000000
r = 50000000
print(sum(1 for x in ok if l <= x <= r))

print(ok)

ok.sort()
print(ok)
```

А теперь бесконечный генератор, который возвращает все числа с 5 нечётными делителями:

https://ideone.com/uiRYDg

```
def getOddPrimesFrom5():
  x = 3
  p = [3]
 
  def isOddNumberPrime(n):
    for x in p:
      if x * x > n: return True
      if n % x == 0: return False  
 
  while True:
    x += 2
    if isOddNumberPrime(x):
      p.append(x)
      yield x
 
def getWith5OddDivs():
  x = 3**4
  p4m = []
 
  for p in getOddPrimesFrom5():
    print('Add new prime:', p)
    p = p**4
    if p < x:
      p4m.append(p)
    else:
      p4m.append(x)
      p4m.append(p)
      print('Now using array:', p4m)
 
      while True:
        x = p4m[0]
        yield x
        x <<= 1
 
        for i in range(1, len(p4m)):
          if x < p4m[i]:
            p4m[i-1] = x
            break
          p4m[i-1] = p4m[i]
        else:
          p4m.pop()
          break
 
for x in getWith5OddDivs():
  print(x)
  if x > 50000000: break
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126502/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy----5--).

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `i+1` во внутренний цикл поставить `int(math.sqrt(i))+1)`.

И нужно ещё проверить, будет ли результат i/d тоже нечетным.

Ещё нужно убрать print(i) в начале цикла,  а последний if подвинуть на один уровень внутрь, чтобы он был в цикле.