# Алгоритм перебора чисел

Tags: python, теория-чисел

Назовём нетривиальным делителем натурального числа его делитель, не равный единице и самому числу. Например, у числа 6 есть два нетривиальных делителя: 2 и 3. Найдите все натуральные числа, принадлежащие отрезку [123456789; 223456789] и имеющие ровно три нетривиальных делителя. Для каждого найденного числа запишите в ответе его наибольший нетривиальный делитель. Ответы расположите в порядке возрастания.

```py
maxi = 0 
for i in range(123456789, 223456790):
    sqrti = i**0.5
    numdel = 0
    if round(sqrti) == sqrti:
        maxdel = 1
        for j in range(2, round(sqrti) - 1):
            if i % j == 0:
                if maxdel == 1: maxdel = i // j
                numdel += 2
        if numdel == 2: print(i, maxdel)
```

отрезок большой и программа  работает эффективно из-за строки

```py
if round(sqrti) == sqrti:
```

как это работает с математической точки зрения?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нахождение пяти нечётных делителей в промежутке чисел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1276027/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb)

Answer (score 1):

Если рассмотреть разложение *n = p<sub>1</sub><sup>e<sub>1</sub></sup>p<sub>2</sub><sup>e<sub>2</sub></sup>p<sub>3</sub><sup>e<sub>3</sub></sup>...* (где *p<sub>i</sub>* - различные простые), то можно догадаться что общее число делителей *n* равно *(e<sub>1</sub> + 1)(e<sub>2</sub> + 1)(e<sub>3</sub> + 1)...*. В это число входят единица и само *n*, конечно.

В задаче требуется найти числа с тремя нетривиальными делителями. Всего делителей тогда будет пять. Пять - простое число, единственный способ представить его в виде произведения - это оно само. Следовательно число с тремя нетривиальными делителями (с пятью делителями вообще) имеет разложение вида *p<sup>4</sup>*. То есть, мы ищем четвертые степени простых чисел, а максимальным нетривиальным делителем будет куб *p<sup>3</sup>*.

Условие `round(sqrti) == sqrti` выполняется только для целых чисел, которые являются квадратами других целых чисел. А так как нам интересны четвёртые степени (которые и квадраты тоже), то условие эффективно сужает число кандидатов.

Ваш пример работает у меня около сорока секунд. Но можно сделать лучше.

Код который перебирает четвёртые степени простых работает 0.05с. Проверка простоты кандидатов написана просто и не эффективно, так как самое большое число, которое надо будет проверять на простоту - 122 (корень четвёртой степени из правого конца диапазона):

```
m = 2
while True:
    n = m ** 4
    if 223456789 < n:
        break
    if 123456789 <= n:
        # is m prime?
        if all(m % i != 0 for i in range(2, m)):
            print(n, m ** 3)
    m += 1
```

> ```
> $ time python nums.py
> 131079601 1225043
> 141158161 1295029
> 163047361 1442897
>
> real  0m0.047s
> user  0m0.032s
> sys   0m0.012s
> ```